# How to store file content sentence by sentence in an array

Tags: perl, file

I want to open a file, and store its content in an array and make changes to each sentence one at a time and then print the output of the file.

I have something like this:

```
open (FILE , $file);
my @lines = split('.' , <FILE>)
close FILE;
for (@lines) {
s/word/replace/g;
}
open (FILE, ">$file");
print FILE @lines;
close FILE;
```

For some reason, perl doesn't like this and won't output any content into the new file. It seems to not like me splitting up the array. Can someone give me an explanation why perl does this and a possible fix? Thanks!

Comment: Did the suggestion work

Comment: second line of your script missing semicolon(;) that is the error.

Comment: Thank you, from the answers below, my error was i needed to add split('\. ' , <FILE>); instead. The only issue im having now, is when i print out the file, all the periods are removed. Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks again!

Comment: @user3646369: Use `join ('.',@lines )`

Answer (score 1):

split needs a regexp. Change `split('.' , <FILE>)` to `split(/\./ , <FILE>)`

Comment: Thank you! This worked! After I made that fix, everything worked, except now when i print the output file, all periods are missing, I assume thats what happens when you split an array, is there a way to remake the array with the periods back in place? maybe the join function?

Comment: Use `join ('.',@lines )`

Comment: What if there are two full stops in a row...?

Answer (score 0):

Change `my @lines = split('.' , <FILE>)` to `my @lines = split('\.' , <FILE>)`

Only `.` is used in regex to match a single character. So you need to escape `.` to split on full stop.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $filename = "somefile.txt";
my $contents = do { local(@ARGV, $/) = $filename; <> };
my @lines = split '\.', $contents;
foreach(@lines){
#lines is an array which contains one sentence at each index.    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what i found was in second line of your script missing semicolon(;) that is the error and also your script is **not capable of handling content of entire file**.It will process only one line. So please find the **modification of your script below**.If any clarification please let me know.

```
my $file='test.txt';#input file name
open (FILE , $file);
#my @lines = split('\.' ,<FILE>); this will not process the entire content of the file.
my @lines;
while(<FILE>) {
s/word/replace/g;
push(@lines,$_);
}
close FILE;
open (FILE, ">$file");
print FILE @lines;
close FILE;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand your point, but my script includes more stuff after the my @lines which forces it to evaluate every element in the array. My only issue is, once i print the file all the periods are removed in the entire txt. Will your solution resolve this? I tried implementing it and it didn't seem to work

Comment: What is all the periods?you mean content of the file?

Comment: @ThiyaguATR no he means the full stops.  The split eats them.

Comment: if i put semicolon and execute the query it is working fine.But it process only first line.That is why i approached my method.



my $file='test.txt';
open (FILE , $file);
my @lines = split('. ' , <FILE>);
close FILE;

print @lines;
for (@lines) {
s/word/replace/g;
#print "$_";
}
open (FILE, ">$file");
print FILE @lines;
close FILE;

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of problems in your code.

- `my @lines = split('.' , <FILE>)` will just read the first line and split it.
- `split('.'` should be `split(/\./`
- `my @lines = split('.' , <FILE>)` no semicolon terminator.
- `print FILE @lines;` - you have lost all your full stops!

Finally I have to wonder why you are bothered about 'sentences' at all when you are just replacing one word.  If you really want to read one sentence at a time (presumably to do some kind of sentence based processing) then you need to change the record separator variable `$\`.  For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = "data.txt";
open (FILE , $file);
my @buffer;
$/ = '.';  # Change the Input Separator to read one sentence at a time.
           # Be careful though, it won't work for questions ending in ?
while ( my $sentence = <FILE> ) {
   $sentence =~ s/word/replace/g;
   push @buffer, $sentence;
}
close FILE;

.. saving to file is left for you to solve.
```

However if you just want to change the strings you can read the whole file in one gulp by setting `$/` to undef.  Eg:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = "data.txt";
open (FILE , $file);
$/ = undef; # Slurp mode!
my $buffer = <FILE>;
close FILE;
$buffer =~ s/word/replace/g;
open (FILE, ">$file");
print FILE $buffer;
close FILE;
```

If you are really looking to process sentences and you want to get questions then you probably want to slurp the whole file and then split it, but use a capture in your regex so that you don't lose the punctuation.  Eg:

```
!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = "data.txt";
open (FILE , $file);
$/ = undef; # slurp!
my $buffer = <FILE>;
close FILE;

open (FILE, ">$file" . '.new');  # Don't want to overwrite my input.
foreach my $sentence (split(/([\.|\?]+)/, $buffer))  # split uses () to capture punctuation.
{
   $sentence =~ s/word/replace/g;
   print FILE $sentence;
}

close FILE;
```

Comment: Hey John, sorry I am new to submitting questions and didn't want to put my entire script in the question because I thought my question was fairy simple, but it seems that I need to provide more context for my question. Should I remake the question on a new thread? My script uses File::Find to go through a selected directory of txt files, finds a specific string and replaces it with another string if the string appears at the end or beginning of a sentence (this is based on what the user decides to declare)

Comment: No that's ok.  I guessed you were probably doing something more complicated than a simple word replace.  Try changing the $/ instead of using split though.  It's much cleaner.

Comment: is this your question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23863315/perl-replacing-strings-from-files-in-directory